# Onde corrijo meu código para poder navegar entre telas?

Tags: javascript, react-native

estou fazendo um simples app com react native. Ele possui uma tela de login e uma tela home. Gostaria que ao clicar no botão login, o usuário seja redirecionado para a página home. Porém o código apresenta o erro abaixo:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ImPzT.jpg

**Abaixo o trecho do código que eu acho que ocorre o erro:**

```
<TouchableOpacity
  style={styles.botao}
  onPress={ () => { this.props.navigation.navigate('Home') } }
>
  <Text style={styles.botaoText}>Login</Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

Bom, se precisarem de mais detalhes sobre o código me avisem.
Agradeço muito a quem puder me ajudar.

Comment: O erro diz que `this.props.navigation` tem valor `undefined`

Comment: você mapeou seus componentes no contexto da navegação?

Comment: Olá @Marconi sou iniciante. Sendo sincero, não sei como fazer isso. Tem alguma forma de entrar em contato contigo? (Pelo discord ou outra plataforma)

Comment: @Arthur é importante vocÊ seguir a documentação da navegação, qual vc está usando?

Comment: @Arthur recomendo esse curso para iniciantes: https://www.udemy.com/course/curso-react-native/